# Apex Rest Callouts in Trailhead Apex Integration Service Module

Tags: apex, httprequest, trailhead

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_intermediate/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts

This is AnimalLocator class.

```
public class AnimalLocator{
    public static String getAnimalNameById(Integer x){

        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/' + x);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> animal = (Map<String, Object>) results.get('animal');

        return (String)animal.get('name');
    }
}
```

However, I was encountered this error when checking challenge.

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: The Apex class does
>   not appear to be calling the REST endpoint using HttpRequest.

I have no idea what it means, but I have call the REST endpoint.

I have added the endpoint to the remote site settings.

And I have executed the code, it returns value. It also passed the test execution.

Comment: It seems everything correct to me .Let me ping jeff if he sees this and helps

Comment: I confirm this issue in my org as well.

Comment: @Himanshu do you have custom domain enabled?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes i have

Comment: Can you try in org that's not custom domain enabled?just to check if that's the issue

Comment: Yah i already thought about that. Testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33418/discussion-between-himanshu-and-mohith-shrivastava).

Comment: Here is the finding, in custom domain disabled org.. If I don't create remote site setting it gives me an error stating "There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint" and once I create that it gives same error mentioned in this question. Custom domain enabled org doesn't consider remote site setting in any way.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thank you, Mohith. Change to Http http = new Http(); will work.

Comment: @Himanshu Change to Http http = new Http(); will work. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=906F0000000MJADIA4

Comment: yes it worked for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered this question in [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=906F0000000MJADIA4). You should post Trailhead related questions in the [Trailhead forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS) for faster assistance.